# Observing a input textbox

Tags: javascript, firefox, textbox, observer-pattern, monitor

I have an input textbox and two buttons, one "Clear" and the other "Save", implemented in xul in a typical layout like this:

```
<textbox id="inputTextbox" placeholder="Enter here a new entry" value = ""
             oninput="enableBtns(event);"/>

<button id="clearBtn" label="Clear" accesskey="C" disabled="true"
           oncommand="clearField();"/>

<button id="saveBtn" label="Save" accesskey="S" disabled="true"
           oncommand="saveEntry();"/>
```

I want to do this: Initially the buttons are disabled. When I put some text in the textbox, the buttons become enabled. If I press one of them, the text is cleared or saved accordingly and the buttons become disabled again.

I can accomplish this functionality easily with the "oninput" attribute, using this code in my js:

```
enableBtns: function(event) {
  document.getElementById("clearBtn").disabled = !document.getElementById("inputTextbox").value; 
  document.getElementById("saveBtn").disabled = !document.getElementById("inputTextbox").value; },
```

My problem now is how to achieve the same functionality for the button status, without the use of "oninput" attribute but making use of an observer. 
So, how do I register an observer when the dialog pane loads, to monitor the textbox for input entry and change the status of the buttons? (if the textbox is not empty)

I have read many related articles on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) but in all cases they mention situations and examples where the observer is used to monitor for changes in extension's preferences. I want to use the observer dynamically as a "sensor" for changes in the textbox. How can i do it..??

Any info, resources and sample code to work on it, will be very appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is assuming that you are developing a Firefox extension, something your question doesn't quite make clear).

I think you might not be seeing the forest for the trees. You mention wanting to have an "observer" for your text input, but using the "oninput" event **is** an observer of sorts (it's technically called an *event listener*). This is the recommended way to operate on XUL controls, and does everything I think you want it to. All you need to do is to handle the special cases that your buttons introduce:

```
clearField: function() {
  document.getElementById("inputTextbox").value = "";
  enableBtns(); // This magically takes care of our button status!
}

saveEntry: function() {
  var value = document.getElementById("inputTextbox").value;
  // 1. Do something with the value here (save it wherever you want)
  // 2. Now you need to decide; do I want to leave the value in the textbox?
  //    Or do I want to clear the textbox? Either way, let's do that next.

  // 2a. If we clear the text box, I might simply call clearField() so it can do
  //     all the work for me.

  // 2b. If we leave the text box alone, you'll need to disable the buttons
  //     manually at this point. Pretty easy.
}
```

I believe the above solution will work for nearly every possibility. The one possibility it may not work for (and you would have to test this; I can't remember exactly how the oninput event gets fired), is if something other than the user modifies the text in the control (i.e. you're scraping data from a page URL). In that case, you would have to do all of your control updates from wherever you're scraping the data. But again, your question does not make it clear if that's your end goal.

One response question I might ask is why do you *not* want to use the oninput event?

Answer (score 0):

If you're including jQuery on your page, then you can use jQuery's change handler:

```
$('#inputTextbox').change(function(){
  var disableButtons = $(this).val() == '';
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

One possible issue you may have with that is it will only fire when the user de-focuses out of the textbox. If you want to immediately react to any keystrokes within the textbox, jQuery's keydown handler might be the better choice:

```
$('#inputTextbox').keydown(function(){
  // your code here
};
```

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

And in order to bind this at the time the window loads, you would wrap it in jQuery's DOM-ready handler:

```
$(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately this is not helpful to me.. Although i know about 
jQuery, i haven't yet "touch" it at all. Currently, i'm interesting to achieve my goal by 
making of use of the observer service only. If it's possible of course. 
Thanks again for your help